# Connecting Crystal Reports 2008 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, database-connection, sql-server-2014

I am trying to connect Crystal Reports to SQL Server 2014. I have integrated security on my db which works great.

When I fire up Crystal Reports I choose from a new connection drop down OLE DB (ADO) and then Microsoft OLE DB provider for SQL Server.

After that at the connection Information I insert `localhost` and choose `Integrated Security`.

The problem is that I cannot see my database in the databases drop down list after this.

Any thoughts?

Is the `localhost` as a server name correct? Why can't I see my databases?

Comment: `localhost` (or `.` or `(local)`) is correct **IF** you installed SQL Server 2014 as the **default** instance without specifying an instance name. Also: the **Express** edition installs as `.\SQLEXRPESS` by default. Only **you** will know what instance name (if any) you choose during setup of SQL Server!

Comment: thank you, as (.) worked, but when i choose my database and move to the next option i get "Not implemented. Details: ADO Error Code: 0x, Source: ADBODB.Connection Description: Object or provider not capable of performing requested operation

Comment: the problem was that my database name had special character in it (.) thank you for your help marc_s

Answer (score 0):

See if you can successfully connect to SQL Server through SSMS using Localhost and windows Authentication using same login you are using for Crystal.

Once you are sure about it then we can look into drivers or other possible issues.